# tensorflow; siamese neural net appears to be meaningless

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to adapt the code I found [here](https://github.com/ardiya/siamesenetwork-tensorflow).

I want to use it on text data.  I've got a global database and a local database that matches up about 90% of the time.  I want to use a siamese neural net to train on the matched stuff, and then apply it on the unmatched stuff in order to find likely matches

`siamese.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

#flags = tf.app.flags
#FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

def mynet(input, reuse=False,
              numFilter = 32,
              convWindow = 2,
              poolwindow = 2,
              poolStrid = 2):
    with tf.name_scope("model"):
        with tf.variable_scope("conv1") as scope:
            net = tf.layers.conv1d(input, numFilter, kernel_size = convWindow,
                          activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME',reuse=reuse)
            net = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(net, poolwindow, strides = poolStrid, padding='valid')

        with tf.variable_scope("conv2") as scope:
            net = tf.layers.conv1d(net, numFilter, kernel_size = convWindow,
                          activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME',reuse=reuse)
            net = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(net, poolwindow, strides = poolStrid, padding='valid')

<about 10 more of these layers>

        net = tf.layers.flatten(net, name = 'flat')

    return net


def contrastive_loss(model1, model2, y, margin):
    with tf.name_scope("contrastive-loss"):
        d = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(model1-model2, 2), 1, keep_dims=True))
        tmp= y * tf.square(d)    
        tmp2 = (1 - y) * tf.square(tf.maximum((margin - d),0))
        return tf.reduce_mean(tmp + tmp2) /2
```

`train.py`:

```
<import a dataframe consisting of labels/strings, addresses and countries and company names>
<convert each entry into a 56-element list consisting of numbers that correspond to a bigram dictionary ('aa' = 1, 'ab' = 2, etc.); pad as necessary>
<mash up all the columns, so for every row, I get a single list consisting of those bigrams; something like [1,45,6,0,0,0]>
<split the data into 'left' and 'right', and give pairs a score of 0>
<shuffle up 'left' and randomly pair with 'right', and give pairs a score of 1>

left_output = siamese01.mynet(left, reuse=False,convWindow=convWindow)
right_output = siamese01.mynet(right, reuse=True,convWindow=convWindow)
loss = siamese01.contrastive_loss(left_output, right_output, label, margin)


global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)


train_step = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.01, 0.99, use_nesterov=True).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

saver = tf.train.Saver()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #setup tensorboard  
    tf.summary.scalar('step', global_step)
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
#    for var in tf.trainable_variables():
#        tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name, var)

    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('train.log', sess.graph)

    #train iter
    for i in range(train_iter):
        b_l, b_r, b_sim = getDummydata(<helper function to provide nicely shaped data>)

        FD = {left:b_l, right:b_r, label: b_sim}
        _, l, summary_str = sess.run([train_step, loss, merged],feed_dict=FD)

        writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
        print("\r#%d - Loss"%i, l)
        b_l, b_r, b_sim = 
    saver.save(sess, "model/model.ckpt") #save every epoch
```

When I run this, I get

```
#0 - Loss 11.6008835
#0 - Loss 21.896631
#0 - Loss 0.19516087
#0 - Loss 0.6260054
#0 - Loss 1.6012161
#0 - Loss 2.767976
...

#0 - Loss 0.010000003
#0 - Loss 0.010000003
#0 - Loss 0.010000003
#0 - Loss 0.010000002
```

So the network appears to be converging.

But, when I apply it to random example in my test set, I get the same answer for every example.  As if all of the convolution filters are going to zero, maybe?

Why would this happen?  What can I try in order to fix it? are 10 convolutions enough?

Some of the columns have only two or three characters, but I convert every column to a 56-element list.  Is that much padding throwing things off?

I've got ~6000 training examples.  Should I get more?  How many more?  60k, 600k?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is well shaped (one-hot or word embeddings), my suspicion either the padding choice (instead of padding every columns, join all columns then pad) or the network is too deep, try simpler network first as baseline.